# How to remove word when it contains x?

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I'm trying to do a replace on a piece of string. For example:
`This is !c-myName!, welcome.`
What I want is that if the string contains `!c-` it should remove the whole string, so:
`This is , welcome.`
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

[Edit:]

When the string contains `!c- blaa!`, it should remove everything until the next `!`, sorry for not clearing that :)

Comment: What if there is `"bla foo!c-qqq and!"` string? What would be the expected result

Comment: @zerkms it should still remove the whole word/string

Comment: @Jay Wit: so it would be `"bla and!"`? Why in the first example `!` is removed, and `,` is not? Both are valid punctuation characters. Provide a definition for the "word" term you're using.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you explain why you need that

Comment: "When the string contains" --- do you realize the difference between "contains" and "starts with"? What's the expected result for `"bla foo!c-qqq and!"` string?

Comment: @zerkms when it contains `!c-`, it should remove the string from the first `!` to the last `!`. So your script should display `bla foo` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "This is !c-myName!, welcome.";
$pattern = '/!c-[^!]+!/';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
echo $result;
```

[fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3ww-baj)

Comment: 1. it's for php. 2. check the question comments and see that it doesn't fit the requirements

Comment: thought it was javascript, it's php now. not sure about what the comments are about but this code will remove all words/strings between `!c-` and `!` which doesn't contain the character `!`

Comment: "between !c- and !" --- where do you see the requirement to remove everything **between** `!c-` and `!`? OP only mentioned that he want to remove the whole "word" if it **contains** `!c-` (though he didn't provide the "word" definition)

Comment: right. But he didn't mention that the word to be removed will always start with `!c-`. But he did say that the word will **contain** it. Do you see the difference between "starts with" and "contains"? The same with trailing `!` - if you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801743/how-to-remove-word-when-it-contains-x/16801953?noredirect=1#comment24216004_16801743 you'll see that it shouldn't end with `!`

Comment: Right. That's why I didn't put such a trivial answer but asked to clarify in the comments